# MOSFET ring oscillator

Tags: rf, circuits

I would like to make a ring oscillator with frequency of 1 GHz with discrete components. What discrete MOSFETs are best for producing the highest frequency possible and are parasitic capacitance and cutoff frequency of MOSFET the only determining factors for the propagation delay of the inverters?

Comment: Discrete MOSFETs are not really suitable for analog circuitry - the capacitances are orders of magnitude too large. The figure of merit is too low for 433MHz. What is the application? If it is for a transmitter at 433.92MHz you need good frequency stability. A crystal or SAW filter is required.

Comment: Look here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558840/can-anyone-explain-how-this-433mhz-rf-transmitter-module-works/558853#558853

Comment: OP has yet to clarify their interest in ring oscillators, or specific high frequencies, for several questions now; this question isn't very interesting, nor much different from the rest of them.

Comment: You need to experiment with Schmitt Trigger and/or Schmitt Trigger inverter, perhaps coupled with Mosfets. I made such a circuit onces. But at the moment, I forgot how it worked.  I should look in my archives.

Comment: @Fredled at edges much shorter than 1/(433 MHz)? Color me surprised!

Comment: A ring oscillator, especially with discrete MOSFETs, is extremely impractical for 433 MHz. You want a resonant oscillator, using a crystal or a high-Q LC tank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MOSFET ring oscillator LT SPICE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691413/mosfet-ring-oscillator-lt-spice)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I never experimented that high a frequency. But it could be tried. Schmitt Triggers are quiet fast. MOSFETS won't be faster anyway.

Comment: @Fredled less concerned with how quickly a Schmitt trigger could react, more how you're going to put out the bandwidth onto a discrete part pin, a trace, and into the next Schmitt trigger while preserving a bandwidth that needs to be at least 7× 433 MHz (to resemble a square wave somewhat, you typically need the first few odd harnonics, hence the 7×)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree. At best you can resonate with propagation delays. Which is already too slow for 433MHz.